# ActiveRecord - Destroy parent if no children left

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I destroy a parent if it has no children left ?
A cart has many wishes, and I want to destroy it if the user has deleted all wishes.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using `RAILS 5` http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/12/Rails-5-supports-bi-directional-destroy-dependency.html

Comment: Thanks, I had to add dependent destroy to the child

class Wish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart, dependent: :destroy

Comment: @AntoineCld how does adding belongs_to :cart, dependent: :destroy worked for you? If you do that, if you delete one wish but there are more remaining, the cart is destroyed as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could determ parent `cart` for `wish` which going to be destroyed before action (`before_destroy`) and check if parent `cart` has any whishes after `wish` destroyed.

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :wishes
end

class Wish < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cart

    before_destroy do
        @cart = self.cart
    end

    after_destroy do
        unless @cart.wishes.any?
            @cart.destroy
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 5

I had to add dependent destroy to the child

```
class Wish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Adding the `dependent: :destroy` to a `belongs_to` works only when there is only a single child record destroyed. It will raise an error when one of multiple children are destroyed. Leaving this comment so other folks don't get stuck if this doesn't work for them.

Comment: Doesn't this mean the cart will be destroyed when the wish is destroyed?